# SQLite: Select and count cases where part of the string (year) is lowar than...?

Tags: sqlite

I did already search in past answers for nearly two days but found no solution. I have a table with a column 'projects', column 'country' and a column 'timeframe'. I want to count the number of projects, grouped by country, which did start before 2017. The data looks like

```
ProjectID   CountryID   Time 
  5             3       Enero/2011 - Diciembre/2020
  6             3       June 2017 - December 2020 
  7             3       June 2017 - December 2030 
  8             5       NULL 
  9             11      July 2017 - December 2020 
  10            11      7/2017 - 12/2020 
  11            5       2017 June - 2020 January
```

The problem is the format of the Time, but as it is a large dataset I cannot change the format manually. I tried my best to do something like

```
SELECT *, COUNT (*)
WHERE (Time LIKE '%XX% - %' AND XX < 2018);
```

but I cannot find the right way to include the parameter XX in the query. Is there any way to get this done without re-writing all data manually?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Strongly suspect you're out of luck, at least without writing your own user-defined function to do the extraction. I would suggest you write some code to split strings like this into their component parts (or at least the years) and use it in a one-time pass to expand this string into four (or two) separate columns (and use it on any subsequent inserts/updates). Working with the individual components will be much easier. (If you really need to, you could keep the original string).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tripehound - substrings did help! For the Start year

```
SELECT ID, substr(TimeFrame, instr((TimeFrame),'20'),4) AS ProjectStart
    , Count(*) AS NumberProjects
    FROM Timeframe
    WHERE ProjectStart>"2017";
```

did do the job; for the end year it was

```
SELECT substr(TimeFrame, instr(TimeFrame,'-')-1+instr(substr(TimeFrame, instr(TimeFrame,'-')), '20'), 4) AS ProjectEnd, 
Count(*) AS ProjectsNumber
FROM Timeframe
WHERE ProjectEnd<"2030";
```

Done!